# How to show all the items when I click the empty QLineEdit (after setting QCompleter) widget in PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

When I type in some character, the QCompleter will pop up items include that character.I'd like to show all the items when I click the empty QLineEdit. I have a solution to work it out by using QComboBox , But I hope to implement it by QLineEdit.
Thanks!

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import division
import sys
from math import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import time

wordlist=['abc','abcv','abdd','asd','bcd']
class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.list1=QStringList(wordlist)
        self.line1=QLineEdit()
        self.completer=QCompleter(self.list1)
        self.completer.setCaseSensitivity(Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        self.line1.setCompleter(self.completer)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget((self.line1))
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.line1.setFocus()
        self.setWindowTitle("QCompleter")


app =QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Use `self.completer.complete()` to force completer popup. Use event filters to catch mouse click.

Comment: @Pavel  Thank you! That works.But  a minor problem still exists.When I click the Qdialog ( filed wrap around the QLineEdit ) , all the items will pop up.But it doesn't work since I click the QLineEdit (where the cursor blinks)..

Comment: Install event filter on the `QLineEdit` itself.